# Use hour meter on well pump to calculate total gallons per time period?

Tags: electric-motor, well-pump, filter

I want to more precisely (but economically) understand my "whole house" filters' efficiency through time and therefore want to measure how many gallons go across them.

It seems that totalizing flow meters are relatively expensive. Some AC hour meters are as inexpensive as $15.

Does anyone have experience with, a design, and specs for using an hour meter on the well pump? The pump "on time" is about 114 seconds (I mention this because most meters stated display/accuracy is 0.1 hours, which is far more than my run time). I measured the volume and extrapolated that to about 11.2 GPM.

As for design, for example, could I use a 120v meter (perhaps they are cheaper?) and just go across a hot and neutral? Also, it would be great to find an inductive meter because this would increase the safety factor and installation ease.

Comment: You can get water flow meters and use a data logger.

Comment: Think you are forgetting that most well pump systems usually have a twenty pound pressure difference.  This will let in errors with an hour meter, more gallons flow at 60# than at 40#.   The math alone might make a flow meter cheaper.

Comment: Residential water meters can be found under 40$ these provide the volume of water actually used, not a WAG that a power meter would provide once you add the calculations. When you start adding inductive pickups the cost will usually be more than a simple inline meter that provides the actual usage verses the same amount of $ and then calculations to provide a wag ok it has a base line guess so a SWAG.

Comment: Use an analog clock, start at 12:00 and have it operate when the pump is running. This may be accomplished with a wiring modification if you are qualified. Cheap and you probably have the clock.

Comment: @crip659 I calculated my rate based on a drawdown test so the delta P you highlight is baked in.

Comment: @Gil Wow...simple is better than complex - what a great idea! A twelve hour clock would give me about 8000 gallons - for my wife and me, that'd be about 2-3 months - so I'd just set a reminder to record the time and then reset the clock to high noon on the first of every month (to be safe). Now, I just have to figure out how to deal (safely) with the lack of a neutral on the pump's 240v circuit (I see 3-wire with ground coming into the pump motor start box - maybe the neutral is hooked up in the service panel).

Comment: You may be able to get a 220V clock for not to much on line. You have to be careful if they are 50Hz or 60Hz. You can compensate for the frequency by adjusting your reading.

Answer (score 1):

> As for design, for example, could I use a 120v meter (perhaps they are cheaper?) and just go across a hot and neutral? Also, it would be great to find an inductive meter because this would increase the safety factor and installation ease.

Not if you want the meter to stop when the pump stops! (assuming a single pole switch)  do you even have a neutral at that location?

Look for a cheaper water meter $30 should be possible in 3/4"

Comment: Most of the hour meters I've seen retain their value across power cycles. You are right about the neutral - I probably don't have one. I was wanting a 1 inch meter if it were economical - all my existing piping is 1 inch PVC - I didn't want to lose any/substantial flow. I'm having a tough time finding a "highly rated"/good lead-free 1 inch water meter for $30-$40.

Comment: it's not about cycles, when the switch is off theres a path from the other hot, through the pump to the meter and then to neutral.    as you go bigger the price goes up. so yeah.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my Pumptrol pressure switch cuts both legs, so I think I'm OK.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a 1" totalizer flow meter for $40 - no luck. (I could buy one for around $115.)

I tried to find an analog clock in the house - no luck.

I ended up buying an inexpensive 250V AC hour meter and small plastic project box. Both for about $21.

I forced the well pump on and heard the gizmo "whirring". It had incremented about 0.05 hours between 1900 last night and this morning at 0900.

We'll see how it goes...
[image: New hour meter near pump control box in remote pump house]